# Django field that stores a list as a comma separated string

Tags: python, django

I'm looking for a solution to store a Python list as a comma-separated string in the database. After doing some research and concluding that Django does not come with something like this out of the box, I decided to write this myself.

This is the model field I've come up with:

```
class CommaSeparatedStringsField(models.CharField):
    def from_db_value(self, value, *args):
        if not value:
            return []

        return value.split(',')

    def to_python(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, list):
            return value

        return self.from_db_value(value)

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        return ','.join(value)

    def value_to_string(self, obj):
        return self.get_prep_value(self.value_from_object(obj))

    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = {'form_class': ListField}
        defaults.update(kwargs)

        return models.Field.formfield(self, **defaults)
```

Pretty simple stuff, and so far, no problems.

The form field and widget associated with this model field should be a multiple select box. Every element in the list is an option in the select field.

In case you're wondering why I want this this way, it's for [Bootstrap Tags Input](https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/), a input widget for entering 'tags' (multiple values). This can work using a textbox but I'd rather represent this field in Python as a list.

Now there's MultipleChoiceField (which uses the MultipleSelect widget) but that has a pre-defined list of options. That's not what I want, in my case the options *are* the data, and I don't care about the selected option(s).

So I wrote a custom form field and widget that subclass the above-mentioned classes:

```
class ListWidget(SelectMultiple):
    def render_options(self, options):
        output = []

        for option_value, option_label in options:
            output.append(self.render_option([], option_value, option_label))

        return '\n'.join(output)


class ListField(MultipleChoiceField):
    widget = ListWidget

    def prepare_value(self, value):
        return [(x, x) for x in value]
```

I overrode SelectMultiple's render_options() to render the data as options instead of the pre-defined choices, and I overrode MultipleChoiceField's validation to remove the choices check and prepare_value to turn the list into a list of tuples (of option_value and option_label).

This works, for the most part. The problem is that it doesn't seem to save the field when it is submitted empty, and I don't understand why. This also happens when I use MultipleChoiceField itself instead of the custom form field and widget I wrote.

I tried to narrow this down using the debugger but I can't find what exactly is happening here. I can see that the form's cleaned data has the correct value (`[]`, empty list), but when the field is saved, it has the old value.

What am I overlooking here?

Comment: What database are you using? If you're using Postgres you can use `ArrayField`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield

Comment: Hey, please do not paste your entire code here. Only the relevant bits as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Makes it easier for us to help.

Comment: @CoryMadden I'm using MariaDB. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: @darthvader1996 Well that's the thing, I'm not sure where the problem lies exactly. All of the code I posted is specific to this case (I didn't post any code that has nothing to do with this problem).

Comment: Well, clearly it's time to migrate to Postgres. :P

Comment: @darthvader1996 I just removed some methods from the classes that are not directly essential to illustrating the problem.

Comment: Hey @Compizfox, I realize this is a long shot, and sorry to contact you here but I don't know how to do it otherwise, as on ServerFault I don't have enough karma to comment: I'm experiencing the exact same problem you had here, it's driving me crazy and don't know what to do about it. How did you solve it? https://serverfault.com/questions/849923/http-503-errors-with-apache-and-mod-wsgi Would be awesome if you can give me any hint, thanks!

Comment: @AndreiO It's been a while and I am not sure what solved it. IIRC a tried a couple of things, and after a while the problem went away. I currently have the option `request-timeout=60` appended to my `WSGIDaemonProcess` line so you could try that. If that's not it, a Django or Apache update probably just solved it.

Comment: @Compizfox thanks a lot for the answer and tips!

Comment: See also [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#jsonfield)